How to extract invoice number from top as first match after word invoice
Invoice contains word Invoice followed by invoice number like IN280625-3/4 in top area of invoice:
Payer:_xxxxxxx
Waybill Invoice_IN280625-3/4 Nimetus_EAN  
Invoice issuer: John
Selle Invoice tasumisel_palume m lisada Kesolev Invoice on poolte
vahel Invoice mittetähtaegsel tasumisel on müüjal õigus nõuda viivist 0,1% tasumata summalt päevas.
Kuni Invoice_IN280625-3/4 payment xxx

Extracting invoice number IN280625-3/4 using c# .NET 8 regex
(?si).*Invoice[\s_:.]+(?<anr>[^\s_]+).+

to group anr returns last match payment since there are multiple occurences of word invoice. How to get first match? Word Invoice may occur in text with combination of different words so search patter cannot enhanced. How to get first word from top of text after word invoice ?
Testcase is in https://regex101.com/r/vvDZpU/1
How to force it to return IN280625-3/4 instead of payment ?
Has .NET 8 RegExp.Match such option?
Passing top of text using
var algus = tekst.IndexOf("Invoice", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
var tekst2 = tekst.Substring(algus, algus + 40);
var cnr2 = @"(?si).*Invoice[\s_:.]+(?<anr>[^\s_]+).+";
var match = RegExp.Match(tekst2, cnr);

Works but maybe there is better option.

I there should be at least a number (?i)\bInvoice[ _:.]+(?<anr>[^\s\d]*\d\S*) https://regex101.com/r/Kpr6WX/1

We can assume that invoice number contains at least one number. However in bottom of text there can be also number in word after Invoice. In this case it still returns last match.

Can there be more than 1 invoice numbers that you want to match? If not, you can just get the first match only. Or make the match more specific (?i)\bInvoice[ _:.]+(?<anr>[A-Z]+\d+(?:[-/]\d+)*)(?!\S) https://regex101.com/r/UgjmQX/1

Change (?si) to: (?mi).

Can you update the example text with a counter example that contains a word with a number after invoice that should not be matched?

I want to get first invoice number starting from top. Yuo regexp returns last match as in https://regex101.com/r/lo3HcP/1

@Andrus That is because you have the global flag enabled, see https://regex101.com/r/wJGZ1k/1 You can use Regex.Match to get the first match.

Regex.Match returns last match. How to disable global flag in C# in single line mode?

@PoulBak Invoice number may occur in next line after word Invoice. Shoud text pre-pocessed and line endings replaced with space? In this case single line mode can used.

@Andrus There is a generated code example here https://regex101.com/r/93roFO/1/codegen?language=csharp which you can see running here https://ideone.com/6Kb03r Don't use the s flag and don't use the .* in the pattern

Invoice number can contains letters, digits, / and - characters in any order. There may me multiple occurences in text of such numbers. You regexp does not return first match if invoice number starts with number. See https://regex101.com/r/hFV6Qq/1

@Andrus If you want to allow only those characters and at least a digit (?i)\bInvoice[ _:.]+(?<anr>[A-Z/-]*\d[A-Z\d/-]*)(?!\S) See https://regex101.com/r/faQ0ts/1

You can omit the s flag and the .* and .+ parts in the regex, and use Regex.Match to get the first occurrence.
If there should be at least a single digit in the match, and the allowed characters are upper and lowercase A-Z, digits 0-9 and / or - you could update the regex to:
(?i)\bInvoice[ _:.]+(?<anr>[A-Z/-]*[0-9][A-Z0-9/-]*)(?!\S)

The pattern matches:

(?i) Inline modifier for a case insensitive match
\bInvoice Match the word Invoice preceded by a word boundary
[ _:.]+ Match 1+ times any of the listed chars
(?<anr> Named group anr

[A-Z/-]* Match 0+ times any of the allowed chars except for a digit
[0-9] Match a single digit
[A-Z0-9/-]* Match 0+ times any of the allowed chars


) Close group anr
(?!\S) Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

See a regex demo and a C# demo
For example
string pattern = @"(?i)\bInvoice[ _:.]+(?<anr>[A-Z/-]*[0-9][A-Z0-9/-]*)(?!\S)";
string input = @"Payer:_xxxxxxx
Waybill Invoice_5IN280625-3/4 Nimetus_EAN  
Invoice issuer: John
Selle Invoice tasumisel palume m lisada Kesolev Invoice on poolte
vahel Invoice mittetähtaegsel tasumisel on müüjal õigus nõuda viivist 0,1% tasumata summalt päevas.
Kuni Invoice  Second280625-3/4 sumiseni k";

Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (m.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["anr"]);
}

Output
5IN280625-3/4

